# How do I set font face in a textmate theme?

Tags: fonts, sublimetext3, plist, textmate

I have a `.tmTheme` I am using with Sublime Text 3. I'd like comments to be in a different font. I am aware that I can use italic or bold, however I would like to use a different font face completely. I have successfully made other changes to the `.tmTheme` (eg, fixing comments so they're displayed with more, rather than less prominence) but I can't seem to change the font. I've been using the `fontName` property.

Here's my existing `.tmTheme` XML:

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Comment</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>comment</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#FFF</string>
            <key>fontName</key>
            <string>Corbel</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

How can I change the font used?

Answer (score 3):

This is not currently possible in Sublime. Although it supports the idea of different buffers having a different font assigned to them, within a single file only a single font face is supported.

Further still, as mentioned in [this forum post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/proportional-fonts-lose-italic-bold-syntax-highlighting/10245/10?u=odatnurd) by one of the Sublime Developers, a font whose glyph width changes between the different font styles is also not supported because it would cause rendering difficulties (or at least, awkward and potentially unexpected text reflow while editing):

> The way the syntax highlighting in Sublime Text works, any change to the buffer can result in the scopes applied to various syntax elements to be changed. Those changes in scope can cause the style to change. Because of that, any font that changes in width via bold or italic can not be used. Otherwise, typing a single character could cause the whole text buffer to reflow and the cursor to jump to a different place, and lines to be word-wrapped int different ways.

Although not (I think) explicitly stated as a rule, the official documentation on [Font settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/font.html) indicates that only a single setting is provided for the font face (although this [can be overriden](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html) as most settings can on a per project/syntax/view basis). Additionally, the documentation on [color schemes](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes.html) shows only that scope styles can contain a font style but not a font face (or size).

Comment: Thanks. Can you add a reference? Then I'll mark it an answered.

Comment: Reference links added for additional background information on this. There may also be a feature request about this (seems vaguely familiar to me) but I'm unable to find it if so.